# Can I edit sender names for email messages I've received in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, headers, mailbox, mime-headers

I use Thunderbird as my email client.

There's an email address in an organization I volunteer in which is used by multiple people; but they don't bother to set their names before the address when they send out email, i.e. it's always "Foo foo@bar.com" rather than "Alice foo@bar.com" or "Bob foo@bar.com".

I can't control what they send. But - I do want to rewrite the sender names in my own mailbox, for archiving my communications with Alice and with Bob.

My questions:

- Can I somehow do this from within Thunderbird?
- If not,

  - can I "legitimately" do it by manually editing the raw mailbox files, or will that mess things up?
  - Is there some other alternative for achieving what I want?

Bonus points if your answer regards editing addresses as well as names.

Comment: Why not use tags or labels? Thunderbird supports those right?

Comment: @Gantendo: Not a bad suggestion, but it would still mean I would need to look someplace other than the Sender to understand who sent me the email; plus, if I reply, it'll use the wrong name.

Comment: I provided an answer for you about names (which cannot be changed) but the answer was disliked. You cannot do what you wish to do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what is wrong with an answer that says you cannot change sender names?

Comment: @John Why delete an answer when its downvoted? You got 47,419 reputation so you surely don't need those 2 rep points

Comment: Because I have a downvote / deletion for every day I have been here for 4 years. That is why.  It is not worth staying as far as I can see

Comment: @John If you receive one downvote per day from now on it would take almost 65 years to reduce your reputation back to 0. I don't think downvotes are a good reason to delete your answers or get discouraged. Especially not if there is no reason given.

Comment: I have edited my response and undeleted @ Gantendo

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the sender name in most email systems because such an action could compromise the email meaning and content.

It is not possible so far as I know in Thunderbird.

Please see:   [Change Thunderbird Email sender](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1070936)

This was from 2015  and anything else I looked at was the same. I have checked Thunderbird fairly closely.

It has never been possible to change the sender name in Outlook in any version going back as far as I remember. I have been using Outlook since 2002.

So, @einpoklum  ,  you cannot do what you are trying to do. Workarounds that I have seen are more work than just accepting what people send to you.